# How to convert latitude,longitude to iOS geo tag ( ISO 6709:2008 )?

Tags: go, gis, latitude-longitude, iso-6709

I need to geo-tag several assets (photos) using [Apple's location format](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadataidentifier/1390699-quicktimeuserdatalocationiso6709) which seems to be actually ISO 6709:2008.

The location data I have is in `latitude,longitude` format so I have to convert to ISO 6709:2008 (e.g. `+48.8577+002.295/`).

Is there any `go` geo-library that I can use or some guidelines how to do the conversion?

Comment: Is it ISO 6709 a latitude/longitude representation?

Comment: yes, it does represent a latitude/longitude along with additional/optional fields. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709